# Request for hot question vote statistics

Tags: support, voting, statistics, hot-questions

Can we get data similar to one [quoted here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231064/165773) but closer approximating hot questions, that is limited to ones with [over 1-2K views](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=views%3A1000)? And preferably [not limited to 180 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220109/request-for-hot-question-vote-statistics/231064?noredirect=1#comment759161_231064).

<sub>Asked here [per advice at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220109/request-for-hot-question-vote-statistics/231064#comment759162_220109).</sub>

---

For your convenience, data referred above is also quoted here (voting on deleted posts is [included](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220109/request-for-hot-question-vote-statistics/231064?noredirect=1#comment759157_231064)). Note this data doesn't take into account whether question was in the hot list:

> Defining "outsider votes" as votes cast by someone who hasn't yet earned even 15 reputation on the site at the time the vote was cast
>
> And looking at all votes cast during the past 180 days
>
> We'll define "outsider agreement" as a case where outsider votes on a post are > 0 and insider (folks who've earned >= 15 rep on the site) upvotes - insider downvotes are also > 0
>
> We'll define "outsider disagreement" as a case where outsider votes on a post are > 0 and insider votes are < 0
>
> Cases of outsider agreement: **2,680**
>
> Cases of outsider disagreement: **277**
>
> Cases where the insiders' votes would've brought a post's score < 0, but outsider votes were present in sufficient quantity to make the post's score positive: **147**
>
> Total posts voted on by outsiders in the past 180 days: **3870**
>
> Total posts voted on by insiders in the past 180 days: **7186**
>
> Total posts voted on by both groups in the past 180 days: **3053**
>
> **Q:** What is the difference between outsider disagreement (277) and insider negative but for outside votes (147)?
>
> **A:** So... Imagine you & I see an answer & we both downvote it. It's at -2. Then 3 people come in with nothing but the association bonus and up-vote it. It's at +1. There are 147 cases like that
>
> Now imagine @enderland and @RhysW both downvote the same answer, so it's at -1 again. There are 277 cases like that.
>
> Total insider votes during the past 180 days: **29,479**
>
> Total outsider votes during the past 180 days: **12,837**
>
> **Q:** am I reading this right -- there were ~700 posts that only outsiders voted on (insiders didn't)?
>
> **A:** something like that
>
> I'm not breaking this down any further right now, but a really common case for that involves answers to questions being upvoted by the asker
>
> **Q:** Ok, so if I'm reading all this right, we have significant "outside" participation, but only in 5-10% of cases does that participation disagree with the community.
>
> **A:** Right. And if you consider that even most of those 5-10% are "controversial" in the sense that they're getting both up-votes and down-votes from insiders, you can see there's a lot to be gained from community education.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so these numbers are for the entire history of the site and include all posts - questions, answers, deleted, closed, whatever. It does not, for what should be obvious reasons, include deleted/retracted *votes*.

- Posts with outsider agreement: 8673
- Posts with outsider disagreement: 685
- Posts where outsider + insider upvotes overrode insider downvotes: 76
- Total outsider-voted posts: 10046
- Total insider-voted posts: 18346
- Total insider + outsider voted posts: 9657
- Total outsider votes: 40171
- Total insider votes: 105718

Ok. So that's a good baseline. Now, here are the numbers for questions that got at least 1K views:

- Posts with outsider agreement: 1023
- Posts with outsider disagreement: 15
- Posts where outsider + insider upvotes overrode insider downvotes: 2
- Total outsider-voted posts: 1055
- Total insider-voted posts: 1210
- Total insider + outsider voted posts: 1054
- Total outsider votes: 8964
- Total insider votes: 15639

Comment: BTW: those two "outsiders override insiders" posts in the 1K+ club? [1](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2658/what-kind-of-business-fields-are-available-to-a-programmer-who-no-longer-wants-t) and [2](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18712/why-are-html-resumes-not-accepted). Probably important to remember that, at one point, *everyone* here was an outsider...

Comment: Things that popped out (not making judgment calls, just saying what I noticed): outsiders voted on 87% of 1k+ view posts, and only 55% of posts overall. Outsiders were 27% of votes on all posts, but 36% of votes on 1k+ view posts. Of course, they agreed with the community most of the time in both cases, but there certainly is more outsider participation on the higher-view posts.

Comment: @jmac per my reading, this data suggests that in hot questions, outsider voting rather closely follows one from insiders. Meaning, whatever problems we experience with these ([1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224750/165773 "promoting questions in a way more suitable for larger scale sites"), [2](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2562/168 "difficulties handling questions with multiple answers")), "outsider disagreement" is probably not one of them (it seems to be more an issue in regular questions - `685-15=670` cases, but we as community would better be able to handle that ourselves)

Comment: Probably also worth noting that 1207 of the 3530 questions asked by new users here have been asked by folks with an association bonus - therefore, that's 1207 "outsiders" able and motivated to vote. On other sites, we tend to see a lot of the "disagreement" arising from questions that no one really cares about except for one or two insiders and the asker.

Comment: @Shog9 one can argue that "able and motivated" doesn't necessarily mean "qualified". Unfortunately, problems involving association bonus are barely noticeable at Stack Overflow, which likely explains why [related feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183109/165773 "The association bonus should not enable users to vote on every site") is `status-ignored`